# machine path of the file uploaded in drupal 7

Tags: php, file, drupal, module, ftp

I am editing a current website right now. I want to change file uploading mechanism from http to ftp. They use File module with Drupal 7. the thing i need is, in a form, when i select which files to upload, how can i get their machine path (e.g. C:\path/to/file.mov)? 
I need this path to use in php ftp_nb_put function.

```
function assets_managed_file_form_upload_submit($form, &$form_state) {


  for ($i = 0; $i < $form_state['num_files']; $i++) {
    if ($form_state['values']['files_fieldset']['managed_field'][$i] != 0) {

      // Make the file permanent.
      $file = file_load($form_state['values']['files_fieldset']['managed_field'][$i]);
      $file->status = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;
      $directory = 'private://cubbyhouse/'. $form_state['values']['allowed_user'];
      file_prepare_directory($directory, FILE_CREATE_DIRECTORY);


      $file->uri = file_unmanaged_copy($file->uri, $directory, FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);
      $file->uid = $form_state['values']['allowed_user'];
      drupal_chmod($file->uri);
      file_save($file);

      //drupal_set_message(t($debug=print_r($form)));

      // Need to add an entry in the file_usage table.
      file_usage_add($file, 'assets', 'image', 1);

      drupal_set_message(t("Your file has been uploaded!"));
    }
  }
}
```

Right now this is how they handle file submitting

Comment: Why you need machine path? are you need file url to display the image or anything else?

Comment: I needed it to use for fopen and eventually ftp_put. But i realized that the problem was whole different. I just get request time out error after 2 mins now.